# errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" in my database

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `shop_1`.`user` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `phone` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `role` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `email_UNIQUE` (`email` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `shop_1`.`address` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `user_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `title_en` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `title_ar` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `city_en` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `city_ar` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `region_en` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `region_ar` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `street_no` INT NOT NULL ,
  `building_no` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  INDEX `fk_address_user1_idx` (`user_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_address_user1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id` )
    REFERENCES `shop_1`.`user` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

I am getting this error :"ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table `shop_1`.`address` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")"

Comment: just run SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS and see the LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR section for details.

Comment: I copied these statements to MySQL Workbench and MySQl 8.0.26 and ran them on an empty schema without a problem. Something else is wrong.

Comment: I also tested and got no error. I think the code posted above is not the code that is causing the error. Are you trying to create the `address` table before creating the `user` table?